# How do I fix LiveChatInc syntax error?

Tags: javascript

In Chrome, I am  receving this error:
 `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on line 1` of _https://secure.livechatinc.com/licence/*(mylicense)*/script.cgi?lang=en&groups=0

[image: error]

The response from that script is:

```
LIVECHAT Control Server xxxxxx (May 26 2015)
```

Here is the script that adds the script.cgi file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
      var license = 'mylicense',
          params = '',
          lang = 'en',
          skill = '0';

      __lc_load = function (p) { if (typeof __lc_loaded != 'function')
        if (p) { var d = document, l = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0], a = unescape('%26'),
          h = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://'); l.type = 'text/javascript'; l.async = true;
          l.src = h + 'gis' + p +'.livechatinc.com/gis.cgi?serverType=control'+a+'licenseID='+license+a+'jsonp=__lc_load';
          if (typeof p['server'] == 'string' && typeof __lc_serv != 'string') {
            l.src = h + (__lc_serv = p['server']) + '/licence/'+license+'/script.cgi?lang='+lang+a+'groups='+skill;
            l.src += (params == '') ? '' : a+'params='+encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(params)); s.parentNode.insertBefore(l, s);
          } else setTimeout(__lc_load, 1000); typeof __lc_serv != 'string' && s.parentNode.insertBefore(l, s);
        } else __lc_load(Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)); }
      __lc_load();
    })();
  //]]>
  </script>
```

The code that is inserting is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://secure.livechatinc.com/licence/mylicense/script.cgi?lang=en&amp;groups=0"></script>
```

Comment: Started seeing this error recently as well. Have you found a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

I work at LiveChat and I checked this issue. I've noticed that you are using the old code and that's probably the reason of the problem. Please try to get the new one from here: https://my.livechatinc.com/settings/code

That should help, but if you would have any problems you can visit our website and start a chat with us :)

Regards!

Agnieszka / LiveChat